# How to adjust Trackpad "Tap Sensitivity" without adjusting mouse speed

Tags: mouse, touchpad, synaptics, multi-touch

Im on Ubuntu 20, GNome Desktop.  The touchpad on my Dell Precision 5550 is huge and just way to sensitive causing lots of undesired effects while typing.

I'd like to keep my "Touchpad Speed" and "Tap to Click" settings where they are but just reduce the tap sensitivity.  Is there a way I can do this please?

Thanks!

Comment: Would love this too, if its not there, can be a request for a future feature?

Answer (score 2):

The problem when you type on your keyboard your palm is being detected as touch pad movements.

The solution is rather detailed but documented by Dell:

- [Precision and XPS: Ubuntu General Touchpad or Mouse Issue Fix](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-ca/000150104/precision-xps-ubuntu-general-touchpad-mouse-issue-fix)

Although the article was published less than a year ago it still references Ubuntu 16.04 instead of 20.04. However the programs discussed, `xinput`, `synaptics` and `libinput` remain the same in both versions (Unless you are using Wayland).

Comment: The question is specifically to the sensitivity - marginally touching the touchpad already triggers a click, causing the cursor to jump.  `synaptics` is no more applicable (unless one wants to return to the synaptics driver). While for some touchpad sensitivity can be controlled using libinput configuration, many touchpads can't. That is what I learned from the libinput documentation.